# Vim automatically indenting tab

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim on Windows 32 bit and while editing **.js** Javascript file, when I type *arrow function* `()=>`it inserts tab at the starting of that line.

#### These are the settings in my **_vimrc**.

```
syntax on
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: Are you looking for `set noautoindent`?

Comment: or maybe `filetype indent on`

Comment: No it doesn't work, it still indents at the starting.

Comment: @ildar, this also don't work. It still indents at the starting.

Comment: Can we get the full output of `:version` and of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: Check https://github.com/MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty - it's for react but I assume it works for normal .js, too.

Comment: I found that "filetype plugin indent on" , was causing problem and one more problem I was facing was that it over indents , but when I disable this my new line comes at the beginning, so is there any way that I can solve this issue and still use this feature?